# Time slots adding through trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time, triggers, schedule, slot

I am trying to have the trigger to add time slots in timeslots table each time the doctor insert a record of his availability in the availability table.

I wrote the trigger, it saved. but when I insert a record into availability, the trigger seems not triggered, yet I do not have any error message.

Can somebody help me? Badly needed.

Here is the code for trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_addSlots] 
ON [dbo].[availability]
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AvailabilityId INT
    DECLARE @SlotStart DATETIME
    DECLARE @SlotEnd DATETIME
    DECLARE @NumberOfSlots INT
    DECLARE @Duration INT
    DECLARE @SlotDoctorId INT
    DECLARE @i INT

    SELECT @AvailabilityId = Id FROM inserted
    SELECT @SlotDoctorId = DoctorId FROM inserted
    SELECT @SlotStart = AvailableFrom FROM inserted
    SELECT @SlotEnd = AvailableTo FROM inserted 
    SELECT @Duration = AppointmentDuration FROM inserted

    SET @NumberOfSlots = CONVERT(INT, (@SlotEnd - @SlotStart)) / @Duration
    SET @i = 0;

    WHILE @i < @NumberOfSlots
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO timeslots(AvailabilityId, SlotStart, SlotEnd, SlotDoctorId, IsAvailable) 
        VALUES (@AvailabilityId, @SlotStart, @SlotEnd, @SlotDoctorId, 1)

        SET @SlotStart = @SlotEnd
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to insert 3 times into availability table, the records are inserted, but no records inserted into timeslots table

Comment: Id DoctorId Date AvailableFrom AvailableTo AppointmentDuration
1 3 2018-03-31 2018-03-31 08:00:00.000 2018-03-31 12:00:00.000 60
2 3 2018-04-01 2018-04-01 08:00:00.000 2018-04-01 12:00:00.000 60
3 3 2018-04-02 2018-04-02 08:00:00.000 2018-04-02 12:00:00.000 60

Comment: Please provide the scripts to create the availablility and timeslot tables so we can recreate the issue.

Comment: i think this is throwing you off: Set @ SlotStart = @ SlotEnd - after the first pass these two will remain equal the rest of the time

Comment: yes, I added another line set @SlotEnd = SlotEnd+@Duration, but still did not work

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will be selected in all your `SELECT ... FROM Inserted` statements? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!